# how do i download ubuntu desktop on wnidows 8 and make a dvd to upload ubuntu to my laptop

Tags: boot, windows-8

I am trying to install Ubuntu desktop to my laptop. I only have windows 8 on a desktop . the laptop has no operating system on it.

if i download Ubuntu desktop on the windows 8 machine how do I burn it to a dvd so that I can upload a clean new install onto my laptop.

what is the latest version of Ubuntu desktop available for download ??

thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest ISO from [Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop).
2. Download [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) or [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
3. Get an empty USB flash drive and follow the instructions from Lili (more user friendly) or Unetbootin.
4. Next time you have a similar problem, use google first.

Comment: Upvoted for #4!